# How to add % sign in mysql table with concat

Tags: mysql, ip

I have created a `config` table in mysql for a project I am developing.

One of the values, the app by default generates an autoconf IP file using the dvb card number and channel id number.

In my app terminal if I configure this on the conf file

IP: 239.101.%card.%number  = this auto generates the multicast IP 239.101.1.1

I built a GUI interface for the project and I am saving this data in a table in mysql which looks like this

```
INSERT INTO `config` (`id`, `name`, `value`) 
VALUES (10, 'autoconf_ip4', '239.101.%card.%number')
```

but when I export this to the `file.conf`, through some other reading info like this autoconf_ip4=239.101.Êrd.%number

The first % goes into some weird character...

and because of the when I start the app the card cannot broadcast its multicast due to wrong configure ip parameters.

Any ideas if this is some sort of mysql error? I am using a varchar (100) to input this data.. am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you jamming this data into a URL where it ends up URI encoded? `%ca` is the `Ê` character. `%nu` is not a valid hex sequence so it appears to be ignored.

Comment: nice so i need to define it as hex? this data can then be edited inside a php config , data gets fetched from mysql db into a web php page to be edited if requested, then after editing it gets saved back into mysql db, and it has a function to export this to a specific folder inside the web page as a  something.conf   file.  This file will then be used by the application on init, to execute the app according to the config file.

Comment: What I'm saying is this shouldn't be happening, and if it is, the way you're transporting that information is suspect. What is this "GUI interface"? Are you submitting arbitrary queries to be executed?